# C++ Builder - Difference between Lib and Res

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++builder

If my understanding is correct:
* Classes compile into obj files. 
* Libs are collections of obj files.

What are .res files? Are they like libs, or is there a difference?

Comment: [Resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599(v=vs.85).aspx). Rather than containing executable code they contain static resources like strings or images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.res files are compiled Windows resources (just like .obj are compiled C++ source code).  They contain bitmaps, icons, etc.

In particular, the C++Builder IDE will automatically maintain a .res file containing the application icon and version info that you've set up under Project -> Options -> Application and Project -> Options -> Version Info.

Answer (score 1):

.res files are compiled resource scripts (.rc)
Can be edited with: http://www.resedit.net/

**More on resource scripts:**
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Scripts

> Here is a list of common resources:
>
> Drop-down Menus
>
> Popup Menus
>
> Text Strings
>
> Keyboard Accelerators (keypress combinations, such as [Ctrl]+[C] to
>   copy text)
>
> Icons
>
> Bitmap Images
>
> Dialog Boxes
>
> Version information
>
> Mouse Cursors

**How to write a resource script:**
http://mirrors.zoreil.com/webclub.kcom.ne.jp/ma/colinp/win32/resources/script.html